# How can I get the value with most occurrences in a collection?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I have a list of `int?` that can have 3 different values: null, 1, and 2.
I would like to know which of them occurs the most in my list. To group them by value I tried to use:

```
MyCollection.ToLookup(r => r)
```

How can I get the value with most occurrence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a Lookup, a simple [GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) would do:

```
var mostCommon = MyCollection
  .GroupBy(r => r)
  .Select(grp => new { Value = grp.Key, Count = grp.Count() })
  .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
  .First()

Console.WriteLine(
  "Value {0} is most common with {1} occurrences", 
  mostCommon.Value, mostCommon.Count);
```